# IPA characters not showing up in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, fontspec, linguistics

I'm new to XeLaTeX and trying to figure out how to use IPA characters. Everything I've read says that I just need to use the `fontspec` package and the characters will show up as intended. Unfortunately, it's not working for me.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Doulos SIL}

\begin{document}

Hello Cruel World

hɛlo kruɫ wɚld

\end{document}
```

The above code shows up as

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome, have you checked that the font you want to use contains the needed glyphs? Where can we get the font?

Comment: @Johannes_B Doulos SIL is specifically designed for IPA. You can download it [here](http://software.sil.org/doulos/).

Comment: I just downloaded the font by clicking on the very big button on the page you linked, unpacked and moved the whole folder in my personal font directory (`./fonts/opentype/`). I copied your example and ran it with `xelatex`. I can see the correct output. Can you show us your log file?

Comment: Which part of the log file? It's too long for me to paste the whole thing.

Comment: My log is less than 500 lines long, that should work. You can post it all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your file needs to be encoded as UTF-8, not Latin1, (or if you're using a Mac Mac Roman) With either of these encodings you will get this output.

Most editors will allow you to resave the file with that encoding. You should also probably set that to be the default for future files.

Output from your file saved as either Latin1 or Mac Roman:

[image]

Output of file encoded as UTF-8:

[image]